# How do I fix error: near "[": syntax error, unexpected '['?

Tags: verilog

I made code that changes 1's complement system to signed magnitude system, but there are errors.

```
module tb_pro(); 
reg [3:0] A ; 
wire t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6;
 wire [3:0] B;
A[3] = B[3];

    AND1 AND0 ( .input1(A[3]), .input2(A[2]), .output1(t1));
AND2 AND1 ( .input1(A[3]), .input2(A[2]), .output1(t2));

OR1 OR1 ( .input1(t1), .input2(t2), .output1(B[2]));


AND1 AND2 ( .input1(A[3]), .input2(A[1]), .output1(t3));

AND2 AND3 ( .input1(A[3]), .input2(A[1]), .output1(t4));

    OR1 OR2 ( .input1(t3), .input2(t4), .output1(B[1]));

    AND1 AND4 ( .input1(A[3]), .input2(A[0]), .output1(t5));
AND2 AND5 ( .input1(A[3]), .input2(A[0]), .output1(t6));

    OR1 OR3 ( .input1(t5), .input2(t6), .output1(B[0]));

initial begin
A=4'b1110;

    #20
    end
endmodule
```

error is

`near "[": syntax error, unexpected '['.`

and

`vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'A'. Is there a missing '::'?`

Answer (score 1):

You must assign to `A[3]` inside an `initial` or `always` block.  For example, change:

```
A[3] = B[3];
```

to:

```
always @* A[3] = B[3];
```

This eliminates your reported compile error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like. `B` is intended to be an output. So the line `A[3] = B[3];` Should be:

```
assign B[3] = A[3];
```